# SWT Virtual Tree not firing SetData event after removeAll/setItemCount

Tags: java, swt

So I have a virtual SWT tree which is populated with data initially, and when a user keys in a filter phrase and refreshes the tree, it alters the data set that the tree pulls it's data from, removes all the entries from the tree and resets the itemCount of the tree to the size of the new dataset. However, after this process completes, the tree doesn't seem to be firing any SetData events which would normally cause the fetch for the TreeItem data, so the tree just ends up being populated by blank entries.

Does anyone know how I can cause the tree to request the data for these TreeItems?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the Tree is created with `SWT.VIRTUAL`. Did you try `setItemCount( 0 );` instead of `removeAll()`? Also, please show the relevant code.

Comment: I'm just waiting on approval from my boss to post the code, since it belongs to a proprietary program. And yes, the tree is created with the virtual flag. It functions normally as a virtual tree up until the point where I remove all the items and attempt to set new ones.

Comment: So, it seems that after the table has been refreshed, and contains the blank entries, if I take the Tree out of focus, by selecting another element of the application, or by selecting another running application all together, it will cause the Tree to begin firing SetData events, and will fill the blank entries with information.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the relevant code. If approval is an issue, you could also build a minimal example that shows the error, Maybe start with an [SWT snippet](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) and modify that until it does what your application is supposed to do and shows the described behavor.

Comment: You can find a snippet at http://pastebin.com/TJQ15qm5 which illustrates my issue. You will need to slip it up into two files, marked by delimiters. If you click the button, the tree should refresh, and you should notice that it doesn't fire events to request info for the tree items.

Comment: I am afraid, the snippet runs just fine (i.e. items show up after refresh) on Win7. BTW the `main` class could have been put into `SOTree` as well.

Comment: Interesting, I'm running it on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.3, using SWT 4.527. I'll attempt to screen capture it's behaviour. Apologies about the `main` class, I have gotten into the habit of writing classes sans-`main` as they are part of a larger software project, so `main` ended up being an afterthought.

Comment: You can find a screen recording at: https://youtu.be/Uw-ty36GrD0

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I'd suggest to [file a bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform)

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in win 7. SetData event is not getting fired